# C seemingly valid 0.1 comparison being skipped

Tags: c, floating-point

I am attempting to write a program that returns to the user the smallest amount of US coins used to make up a dollar amount (US currency) that the user enters.

My problem: When the program reaches 0.1, the program does not subtract a dime, but instead subtracts a nickel and 5 pennies. This only occurs with numbers larger than 1.85. When less than 1.85, a dime is successfully subtracted.

Here is my code:

```
 while (Money >= 0.25){
   Money = Money - 0.25;
   Coins = Coins + 1;
   printf ("Current money: %f \n", Money);
 }
while (Money >= 0.1) { 
  Money = Money - 0.1;
  Coins = Coins + 1;
  printf ("Current money: %f \n", Money);
}
while (Money >= 0.05) {
 Money = Money - 0.05;
 Coins = Coins + 1;
 printf ("Current money: %f \n", Money);
}
while (Money >= 0.01) {
 Money = Money - 0.01;
 Coins = Coins + 1;
 printf ("Current money: %f \n", Money);
}
```

Here is my output when using the number 2.1:

```
2.1
Current money: 1.850000 
Current money: 1.600000 
Current money: 1.350000 
Current money: 1.100000 
Current money: 0.850000 
Current money: 0.600000 
Current money: 0.350000 
Current money: 0.100000 
Current money: 0.050000 
Current money: 0.040000 
Current money: 0.030000 
Current money: 0.020000 
Current money: 0.010000 
Used 13
```

And this is my output when using the number 1.85:

```
1.85
Current money: 1.600000 
Current money: 1.350000 
Current money: 1.100000 
Current money: 0.850000 
Current money: 0.600000 
Current money: 0.350000 
Current money: 0.100000 
Current money: 0.000000 
 Used 8
```

why is this happening? Why are dimes not being used in numbers larger than 1.85?

Comment: You should read this — http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html And should not use floating point for monetary calculations but rather go with fixed point (and some acceptable rounding).

Comment: @VladLazarenko Love it. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because 0.1 doesn't necessarily mean 0.10000000000000000... .  You're only seeing the numbers to the precision that `printf` is showing for a `%f`.  If you step through this and look at the values in your debugger, you'll probably see that at the end of your 2.1 loop, the value is something like 0.099999999 which is < 0.10.

This is why you shouldn't use floating-point values (`double`) for currency. Instead, you should use something like C#'s `decimal` numbers, which don't rely on binary floating-point values. Here is [an implementation in C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3667/A-Decimal-Class-Implementation).

In your case, simply keeping an integer number of cents (and understanding that you need to divide by 100 to get dollars) will make your calculations exact.

```
int money = 281;  // $2.81

while (money >= 25) {    // Quarter
   money -= 25;
   coins++;
   printf("Current money: $%d.%d \n", money/100, money%100);
}
//...
```

Thanks to Vlad for this link: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: This answer is all over the place. Floating point vs fixed point is not the issue here. The real issue is binary vs decimal.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hmm, How do you propose I answer differently?

Comment: Exactly as I said. The solution is to use a decimal number system rather than binary.

Comment: Isn't (for example) C#'s `decimal` a fixed-point number system?

Comment: No. It is not. It is a decimal floating point value. If you would just read the article to which you linked, then you could understand all this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: What article - I have go through the page and I haven't found any link you would post.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you, I was confusing terminology. Something like the `decimal` type is what I intended.

Comment: @Maciej Er, that comment was addressed to the author of this answer. But you linked to the same article too. You also should read it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Sorry. I misunderstood the conversation flow (and IEEE decimal is IMHO not something widely used - at least in areas I'm most familiar with).

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka It doesn't matter whether or not IEEE decimal is widely used. It isn't. I just think we should diagnose the problem accurately. As to what the best solution is, in C that's far from clear. But let's be clear that this issue is binary vs decimal rather than fixed vs floating.

Answer (score 2):

[What every programmer should know about floating point numbers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Welcome to wonderful world of floating point numbers. The 0.1 and 0.01 are not represented exactly (similar as 1/3 have no final decimal representation). My guess is that 0.10 in first example is in fact 0.099999999998 or similar number. Hence  0.099999999998 < 0.10 and the comparation fails.

There are 2 solution to this:

- Don't use floating point numbers but use fixed point representation (number of cents)
- Use epsilon comparation. I.e. `if (x - 0.005 >= 10) { ...`

Personally I would recommend the first solution.

**Example**: In the following text I will use decimal 3 s.f. numbers and 1/3 and 1/999 for simplicity (coin calculation for 3-finger aliens was outsourced to Earth).

Your code is roughly:

```
while (money >= 1/3) {
    money -= 1/3;
    coins++;
}
while (money >= 1/999) {
    money -= 1/999;
    coins++;
}
```

After compilation it looks like:

```
while (money >= 0.333) {
    money -= 0.333;
    coins++;
}
while (money >= 0.001) {
    money -= 0.001;
    coins++;
}
```

Let's input large number say 10. Then after initial run we have:

```
money = 10 - 0.333 = 9.667 ≈ 9.67
money = 9.67 - 0.333 = 9.334 ≈ 9.33
money = 9.00 - 0.333 = 8.667 ≈ 8.66
...
money = 1.00 - 0.333 = 0.667 ≈ 0.667
money = 0.667 - 0.333 = 0.333 ≈ 0.334
money = 0.334 - 0.333 = 0.001 ≈ 0.001
// Next loop
money = 0.001 - 0.001 = 0.000
```

Ups - we counted one coin too much.

Comment: Again, floating point can represent 0.1 exactly, so long as you use a decimal system rather than binary.

Comment: @David: And how many compilers do you know that suppoers that, even more so, that defaults to it? I learned a very long time ago that money in computers is dealt with as integers - large ones if need be, and maybe as a pair of "main currency, fractional parts" integers, but integers all the same.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Plenty of compilers support decimal floating point. This is a greatly misunderstood area. People think that the problem is floating point when in fact the issue is using base 2 rather than base 10.

Comment: On commonly available hardware, and support in for example printf to do the right thing? Yes, I'm well aware of "bcd float" - there is even a mode in x87 to use that. But I'm not aware of much support for it. And of course, it won't solve the fact that some complicated math came up with an answer that isn't EXACTLY a match for some hard-coded number, etc.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: True but using decimal floating numbers will only partially solve this particular - the `for (double a = 0; a < 1; a += 1/3)` won't work as expect there either - or you will still have numbers `a <<< double.MAX` such that `a + 1 = a`. Or `a + (b + c) ≠ (a + b) + c`.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka Why would you work with `1/3` in `decimal`?!! That's like saying that decimal is useless because it can't represent pi! Please try to stick to the topic.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It was an example. Tertiary in decimal is like decimal in binary. I haven't said that decimal is useless (I mean - i use decimal daily if I write some numbers - practically any numbers ;) ). I disagree that solution is simply decimal because continuing example above - if I have `1000_3` in 3 s.f. subtractinc `0.1_3` won't change a thing. IMHO it is first problem people are likely to encounter with fp representation and it is wonderful opportunity to educate them.

Comment: As of decimal - I don't think it is silver bullet. You can still get rounding errors with large/small numbers. You still pay price for representing much wider range (say 10e-7) then you need. Futhermore it may not matter in this case but simply changing to decimal without additional understanding might hunt if you say change from monthly payments to yearly or price per gallon to price per liter.

Answer (score 1):

Because floating-point numbers aren't exact.

Usually, these kind of numbers are represented using the [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) floating-point format, it's sort of a binary encoding. But not every fraction/rational/real number can be represented in binary, so it may be the case that your 1.85 is actually 1.8499274 or 1.85010374 or whatever.

That's why you should never rely on comparisons by the `==` and `!=` operators; you should instead check whether two numbers are close enough to each other:

```
const float eps = 1.0e-5;
if (abs(number1 - number2) < eps) {
    // let's pretend they're equal
} else {
    // they aren't equal
}
```

For further reference, I advise you to read [this paper](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), it explains everything in detail so you'll have a deeper understanding of floating-point numbers.

Comment: You've got two upvotes though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems all stem from the use of binary floating point, i.e. `float` or `double`. Many of the numbers in your question are not exactly representable using binary. Exactly representable numbers in binary floating point are of the form k/2^n where k is an integer and n is a non-negative integer.

So, these values are not exactly representable:

```
0.1
0.05
0.01
2.1
1.85
1.6
1.35
1.1
0.85
0.6
0.35
```

and so on. Scary isn't it?!

Because the numbers you are working with cannot be represented exactly, you are subject to round-off error. And that's why your program does not behave the way you desire.

The standard reference on floating point arithmetic is: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

This excellent work covers floating point arithmetic at a fundamental level. It is not restricted to binary floating point. It also considers representations using the decimal system. And this is the real key to solve your problem. To make your arithmetic accurate you need to use decimal rather than binary representations. If you do that then you can represent the currency values exactly.

Sadly, common C implementations do not come with decimal floating point or fixed point data types. So you will need to either roll your own, or find a third party library.

As a very simple solution, assuming that you only ever need to represent up to 2 decimal places, you can use a fixed point decimal representation. Store your values in `int` variables and assume an implicit multiplicative shift of `100`.

Comment: Wow, why did your and @H2CO3's answers get downvoted?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Well, I certainly did wonder that!